# Multiply two columns and display in new one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having 3 tables named `customers`,`cars`,`carrent`. All i want is to multiply `rentorder.days` with `cardetail.rentday` and show the value in `rentorder.totalrent`. I am unable to achieve this. How can i do this.
Any suggestions please.

**SQL**

```
SELECT customers.*, 
       cardetail.carname, 
       cardetail.model, 
       cardetail.company, 
       cardetail.color, 
       cardetail.rentday, 
       rentorder.days, 
       rentorder.totalrent 
FROM   rentorder 
       INNER JOIN customers 
               ON customers.custid = rentorder.custid 
       INNER JOIN cardetail 
               ON cardetail.id = rentorder.carid
```

Comment: "show the value in `rentorder.totalrent`" - Do you want just to show it, or save it in `rentorder` table?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel i want to save it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply `rentday` with `days` to get the computed value `totalrent` in `Select` list.

Try this

```
SELECT customers.*, -- Not sure this is allowed in [Mysql]
       cardetail.carname, 
       cardetail.model, 
       cardetail.company, 
       cardetail.color, 
       cardetail.rentday, 
       rentorder.days, 
       cardetail.rentday * rentorder.days AS totalrent 
FROM   rentorder 
       INNER JOIN customers 
               ON customers.custid = rentorder.custid 
       INNER JOIN cardetail 
               ON cardetail.id = rentorder.carid
```

To save the data you need to use `update` from `Inner Join` syntax

```
update rentorder 
       INNER JOIN customers 
               ON customers.custid = rentorder.custid 
       INNER JOIN cardetail 
               ON cardetail.id = rentorder.carid 
SET
    rentorder.totalrent = cardetail.rentday * rentorder.days
```

Comment: "SELECT customers.*, -- Not sure this is allowed in [Mysql]" - It is!

Comment: @VR what if i want to save the value?

Comment: "SELECT customers.*, -- Not sure this is allowed in [Mysql]" - It is! - Only if the first one. SELECT col1, table.* doesn't work.

Comment: @endo64 i just tested `select productIdata, categories.*` - it works on MariaDB. I often did that on MySQL too (for debuging queries).

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, I just tested on 5.5.47 and 5.6.17, it doesn't work, may be it works on 5.7.x. Which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: @endo64, tested `SELECT t1.col1, t2.*` on 5.1.49 and 5.6.21 - it works. `SELECT col1, t2.*` also works, if `col1` is unambiguous.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, thank you for testing. It is very strange, I tested on both Ubuntu and Windows. Here my SQL `use mysql; select User, * from user;` and the result `...near '* from user' at line 1`

Comment: @endo64, you are using `*` without a table alias like `t1.*` - That is not the same. With `SELECT col1, *` - `*` will include `col1` - That means, you are selecting `col1` twice.

Comment: Ah, got it now! Thank you!